# How to analyze my repeated measures data?

Tags: repeated-measures, categorical-data

I have data on 200 subjects with baseline data and follow-up data after 1 and 2 years. The dependent variable is nominal: whether each subject lives at home, has passed away or lives in an institution (all subjects live at home at baseline).

I have several independent variables, some of which have been repeated at follow-up measurements, some are only available at baseline. I'm primarily interested in one independent variable that is only measured at baseline, and whether it predicts the course of that subject (if they can remain living at home).

Can anyone help me with which analysis to choose? Tips in general or specific for SPSS and/or SAS are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have data on the dates that the individuals moved into institutions or died? If so, survival analysis with competing risks (moved to institution, died) comes to mind, at least for relations to baseline information.